# How can I change the background color of the title bar in an android emulator in VS 2022

Tags: c#, android, xaml, maui, titlebar

I'm writting a .NET MAUI solution that is suppose to run on android, and currently has two pages. When I start it up the program runs fine and looks like this:

[image: Android Emulator]

I  also added a Flyout menu which I initially thought wasn't there because the menu lines are displayed in white. When I clicked on the spot where the flyout menu is the new page appeared.

So my question is, how can I initially change the background color of the title bar?

I reviewed videos on how to change background color but was unable to come up with any answers.

Comment: Have you checked `styles.xml` and `colors.xml` in your project?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what the problem is, or what you have tried but to change the NavBar per Page you add `Shell.BackgroundColor` to your `ContentPage`:

```xml
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MauiTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Shell.BackgroundColor="Blue"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="True">
```

The color can also be set through the [`Shell` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/pages?view=net-maui-8.0#set-page-colors)

```xml
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiTest.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiTest"
    BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">
```